# Laravel - auth()->refresh() is undefined in JWT AuthController?

Tags: angular, laravel, authentication, jwt, token

I'm creating a Laravel + Angular application, and I use JWT.
(I follow the tutorial but I get an error in the middle).

I already have a Laravel and Angular project, and when I created the laravel project I didn't specify any authentication (I even deleted the User migration).

Since they are existing project, I don't want to start over. 
I ran the following commands to use JWT in my angular project:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
php artisan jwt:secret
```

After that I copied the default router to api.php:

```
Route::post('login', 'ApiController@login');
Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.jwt'], function () {
    Route::get('logout', 'ApiController@logout');
    Route::get('user', 'ApiController@getAuthUser');

});
```

And extended the existing User.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
```

And I copied the required fields into config/auth.php.

In the next step I had to copy this into AuthController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the public function refresh() method it gives me the following error:
"Undefined method 'refresh'. intelephense(1013)"
(The same for factory)

Why are they undefined? Do I have to include something to the class?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `auth()` without specifying any argument, it uses the default authentication guard from your `config/auth.php` file, you probably didn't  replace it with your JWT guard.

Comment: I did, this:

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

...

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

Answer (score 1):

i know it's too late. But you can suppress error message by doing this

```
public function refresh()
{
    /** @var Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager */
    $auth = auth();
    return $this->respondWithToken($auth->refresh());
}
```

Hope this help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the auth guard has not been registered correctly. I'd start debugging by checking if the AuthGuard is actually extended in `src/Providers/AbstractServiceProvider::extendAuthGuard` of the package.

Comment: In app/Providers, I only have AuthServiceProvider and AppServiceProvider, there is no AbstractServiceProvider

Comment: I should have been clearer. The entire path to the file would be something like `./vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/AbstractServiceProvider.php`

Comment: I just noticed that I don't see a route to the register method in your controller. Do you have it and if so, is it within the `'auth.jwt'` middleware route group?

Comment: I found the AbstractServiceProvider.php, and in it I found this: "protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'jwt.auth' => Authenticate::class,
        'jwt.check' => Check::class,
        'jwt.refresh' => RefreshToken::class,
        'jwt.renew' => AuthenticateAndRenew::class,
    ];"

Comment: for your second answer: if youre talking about register method in AuthController.php, I don't have one. I copied exactly from "https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/#update-your-user-model", and there was no register method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this complete method of refresh.

public function refresh(){

```
return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success',
    'user' => Auth::user(),
    'authorisation' => [
        'token' => Auth::refresh(),
        'type' => 'bearer',
    ]
]);
```

}